# Is any difference between a MaterialButton and a simple Button?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-button, material-components-android

If I set **Theme.MaterialComponents.Light** as my main theme, will be any difference between these two buttons if I use them in an xml layout?

```
<Button />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton />
```

As I saw they behave both as MaterialButtons.
If I want to get the behavior of the old plain button, I have to use:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you are using a **MaterialComponents Theme** there is **no difference** between `<Button />` and `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton />`.

There is an **auto-inflation** enabled which **will replace** `<Button` with `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` at runtime.

The [`MaterialComponentsViewInflater`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java#L57) replaces some framework widgets with Material Components ones at inflation time, provided if a MaterialComponents theme is in use.
Something similar happens also with AppCompat (you can check that `MaterialComponentsViewInflater extends AppCompatViewInflater`).

It means that, the `<Button` is replaced `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` at runtime, if you are using a MaterialComponents Theme.

> If I want to get the behavior of the old plain button, I have to use:
>   `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton />`.

It is an option, but not necessarily.
It depends by what you want to achieve. You can also config a custom style since the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` style  inherits by `Widget.AppCompat.Button` style.

[It is the difference](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/71048025effed62c6f965e77e532fa884d8266ca/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/values/styles.xml#L25):

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="enforceMaterialTheme">true</item>
    <item name="enforceTextAppearance">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_right</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_top</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:insetLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">@dimen/mtrl_btn_inset</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">@dimen/mtrl_btn_inset</item>
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator" ns2:ignore="NewApi">@animator/mtrl_btn_state_list_anim</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">@null</item>
    <item name="elevation">@dimen/mtrl_btn_elevation</item>
    <item name="iconPadding">@dimen/mtrl_btn_icon_padding</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/mtrl_btn_ripple_color</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearance">?attr/shapeAppearanceSmallComponent</item>
  </style>
```