# What is alternative of android:background in MaterialComponents?

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

Question:  android:background is not giving effect in MaterialComponents.

In my project, I was using AppCompat

( `<style name="DayTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`)
and everything was working fine.
but, because of some requirement in my project, now, I've to use MaterialComponents

( `<style name="DayTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">` )

And because of that some UI looks bad.

Problem: In AppComapt, I was using  `android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_btn"` which was working fine, but in MaterialComponents, this background is not giving effect.

I tried to change color, shape n all but it's not giving effect.

```
 <Button
                                android:id="@+id/custom_category_image"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_btn"
                                android:text="A"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="12dp"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp" />
```

(I'm using button, because, instead of any fixed image, I'm setting the first letter of title in this button and this button is actually inside carview, so it'll be cirlce also.)

**bg_circle_btn:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="?attr/toolbarcolor" />

    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp" />
</shape>
```

Please note that, in whole project, I need to use this background, so please do not give any other alternative ways.

Comment: Can you post a screen with the shape?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I can't capture because of some changes are going on. But I'll provide it and I tell you, it is not giving in roung shape, also, button is not coming in exctly center instead it is hiding on left bottom side'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **`androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton`** instead of `Button`. This will solve your problem.

Besides this you can use `android:backgroundTint` to change the color only.

To change both (**Shape&Color**) for **`com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`**, you have to do this from you code:

`setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_circle_btn)` `setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED))`

Comment: Then you could use `setBackgroundResource` from code for shape and `android:backgroundTint` from xml for color. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Could you please add your button layout? I don't know whats going on here. I have tested and its working.

Comment: Change your button **width** and **height** to **wrap_content**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200601/discussion-between-md-asaduzzaman-and-priyanka-singh).

Comment: I did something and now it's showing in circle, but inside button text is not exactly in centre instead it is showing in downside.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman pay attention with `setBackgroundResource()`. It calls the `setBackgroundDrawable`  with this warning in logcat: `Do not set the background; MaterialButton manages its own background drawable.`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the Material Components theme, `<Button>` is replaced by the `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>` at runtime. There is an `auto-inflation` ([check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925853/is-any-difference-between-a-materialbutton-and-a-simple-button)).

To change the background color just use the `app:backgroundTint` attribute.
It works **with a color**, not a drawable.
Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   app:backgroundTint="@color/...."
   ../>
```

If you want to apply a custom background to the `MaterialButton`:

- you can use
  **`android:background`** in `MaterialButton` but it requires at least the version `1.2.0-alpha06` (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908045/how-to-set-a-gradient-background-in-a-material-button-from-material-components/61610556#61610556))
- use an `AppCompatButton` as suggested by [@Md. Asaduzzaman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302128/2016562)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `background` attribute, when using `MaterialComponents` theme.

You can only change its color using `backgroundTint` attribute.

Possible way of achieving your task is to use View/Layout, then providing a shape background on it.
For example using CardView, you can do this as follow.

You cannot use `background` on `CardView`, but using some of the `CardView` useful attributes you can achieve your task:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:cardCornerRadius="65dp">
    <Widget_You_Want />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score -1):

For a round circle you could use shape theming with Material Components. You would probably want to define a `ShapeAppearance` like

```
<style name="ShapeAppearance.Round" parent="">
  <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
  <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

Then apply that to your button (or button style) with `app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.Round"`