# Android studio - gradient background & stroke

Tags: java, android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I am trying to give my button a gradient background and stronger stroke. I have read/seen many tutorials but nothing works for me.

This is my addon .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient android:startColor="#25AAFF"
        android:endColor="#004F81">
    </gradient>

    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#000000">
    </stroke>

    <corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>
```

NOTE: The corners work fine

and Button file

```
     <Button
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_password_input"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/login_button_text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </Button>
```

Comment: Are you using the Material Components library?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Material Components Library there is no difference between `<Button />` and `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton />`. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925853/is-any-difference-between-a-materialbutton-and-a-simple-button/57926083#57926083) for more info.

`MaterialButton` **ignored** `android:background` until release `1.2.0-alpha06`.
With this release you can have a gradient background using something like:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button_gradient"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    ... />
```

Also you can apply the stroke using the `app:cornerRadius`, `app:strokeWidth` and `app:strokeColor` attributes:

```
<Button
    app:cornerRadius="4dp"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/primaryLightColor"
    ..>
```

If you are using an earlier versions of the material components library you can use the `AppCompatButton`:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button_gradient"
    ..>
```