# Custom Button not completly shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-button, material-components-android

I tried to set a drawable as a background for  a button, but just the corners are rounded now.

Here is the code for the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="1000dp"/>

    <solid android:color="@color/light_notlight_themebased_accentColor" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp" />

    <stroke
        android:color="@color/ContrastAndText"
        android:width="10dp" />
</shape>
```

And here is the code for the Button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_loginbutton_default"
            android:text="@string/login_loginButton"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/NavbarAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

The stroke and the color is not shown (it stays the backgroundcolor), only the corners are rounded...

Here is what it looks like:

*In the AndroidStudio Preview (Canary 4.1):* [image: In the AndroidStudio Preview (Canary 4.1)]

*Final result on the device:*

[image: Final result on device]

Whats my fault? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the Material Components library and which version?

Comment: Yes, I am. _implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a MaterialComponents Theme there is no difference between `<Button />` and `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton />`. Check this answer for [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925853/is-any-difference-between-a-materialbutton-and-a-simple-button/57926083#57926083).

If you want to use the **`android:background`** attribute  in your `Button` you have to use the version `1.2.0-alpha06` or higher.

```
<MaterialButton
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    ... />
```

Otherwise you have to use the `AppCompatButton` component.

Checking your shape you don't need to set a background.
Just use

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:cornerRadius="@dimen/..."
        app:strokeColor="@color/.."
        app:strokeWidth="@dimen/.."
        ..>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just used the AppCompat Button now and it works perfectly :)