# Gradient color using MaterialButton and shapeAppearance

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles, material-components-android, material-components

I want to make a `Button` like this one :
[image]

I try it using `style` with `shapeAppearance` :

```
<style name="ShapeAppearance.Button" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">@dimen/button_corner_radius</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">@dimen/button_corner_radius</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">5dp</item>
</style>

<dimen name="button_corner_radius">40dp</dimen>
```

I apply the style in my MaterialButton like this :

```
app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.Button"
```

The result is :

[image]

Now, I try to put a linear gradient :

- #DF2D48 @ 0.0
- #D72D46 @ 0.2
- #AF223B @ 0.5
- #AC2139 @ 1.0

For example :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#DF2D48"
        android:centerColor="#D72D46"
        android:endColor="#AC2139"
        android:angle="360" />
</shape>
```

and I apply it using in my Shape style :

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/test</item>
```

But the result is the same. Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Gradient color using Material Button:**

[image: Gradient MaterialButton]

**MaterialButton :**
To use a custom drawable background with the MaterialButton background tint attribute should be null ref code:
app:backgroundTint="@null"

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:text="@string/button_enabled"

                app:backgroundTint="@null"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_1"
               />
```

**Gradient with shape:** res/drawable/gradient_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#DD8E54E9"
        android:startColor="#CC225AE0" />
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="18dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="18dp"
            android:topRightRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            />
        <stroke
            android:width="6dp"
            android:color="#007879E8" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Tested with `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` and it became **dark** but this did the trick: `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton`

Comment: for me it is worked following version:
i am using : material:1.3.0-alpha02
theme:<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">  if i get any better solution than this, I will share you

Answer (score 5):

About the `MaterialButton`:

- it uses a **`MaterialShapeDrawable`** to apply the `shapeAppearance` (shape and stroke).
  Currently (`1.3.0`) the `MaterialShapeDrawable` **doesn't support** a gradient background.
- it supports the **`android:background`** attribute only starting from the [`1.2.0-alpha06`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61610556/2016562).   But using the **`android:background`** the `MaterialButton` **removes** the default `MaterialShapeDrawable` background and the `shapeAppearance` is **not** applied.
- if you are using a **MaterialComponents Theme** there is **no difference** between `<Button />` and `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton />` because of the [`MaterialComponentsViewInflater`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925853/is-any-difference-between-a-materialbutton-and-a-simple-button/57926083#57926083) that replaces the `Button` with a `MaterialButton` at runtime.

You have 2 solutions:

- to use a custom shape with custom rounded corners and a gradient color and apply it as `android:background` to `MaterialButton`
- to use a custom shape and apply it to an `AppCompatButton`.

With **`MaterialButton`** :

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_shape"
        />
```

[image]

Make sure to null out `backgroundTint` (either `app:backgroundTint="@null"` or `app:backgroundTint="@empty"`), to avoid that the custom background doesn't get tinted.
**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.2.0-alpha06`**.

With **`AppCompatButton`** :

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
      android:background="@drawable/gradient_shape"/>
```

[image]

with a shape like:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="...."
        android:startColor="...." />

    <corners android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because I try to set a background to a MaterialButton, and it's not possible.

Finally, I've used a classic Button with this background :

```
<shape xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#D72D46"
        android:centerColor="#AF223B"
        android:endColor="#AC2139"
        android:angle="360" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: To use the `android:background` attribute in `MaterialButton` you need at least the release `1.2.0-alpha06`

Comment: I tried it but this solution ignore the "app:shapeAppearance"

Comment: Yes it is an expected result. Using `android:background` the `MaterialButton` doesn't use the `MaterialShapeDrawable` and the `shapeAppearance`. Also be aware that the `Button` is auto-inflated as a `MaterialButton`.