# why i can'nt be able to change the color of buttons

Tags: android-studio, android-button, chrome-app-developer-tool

I have added new colors in color.xml and set those color in main.xml file to buttons but the color of my buttons is still blue/default i don'nt know why this happen.
if anyone know what is the problem then please help me to solve this issue.

> > Code of color.xml file is:

```
<resources>
<color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
<color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
<color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
<color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
<color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="share_button_color">#271B1B</color>
<color name="next_button_color">#21EA13</color>
```

> > main.xml file code is:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sharememe"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="share"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline3"
    android:onClick="Sharememe"
    android:background="@color/share_button_color" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextmeme"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline3"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="269dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="540dp"
    android:onClick="Nextmeme"
    android:background="@color/next_button_color"/>
```

AVD image before add colors is :

[image: before]

AVD image after add colors is :

[image: after]

.

Answer (score 0):

Material buttons use `backgrountTint` attribute to colorize their background not `background` attribute, So replace `background` attribute with:

```
<Button
    ...
    app:backgroundTint="@color/next_button_color"/>
```

Comment: okay thankyou soo much dear. May GOD bless you.                                                                      Can you please tell me difference b/w material button and simple button?

Comment: You're welcome, If the answer helped mark it as the accepted answer to help others as well. Material button are normal buttons styled per [Google Material design guidelines](https://material.io/design/guidelines-overview), including shadow, inset, corner radius, touch gestures, etc. which is drawn on all API versions the same by the help of [Android support library](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started).

Comment: @MUHAMMADHASEEB About the difference you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925853/is-any-difference-between-a-materialbutton-and-a-simple-button/57926083#57926083